# Adding constraints on tables with circular foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

We have users in our system that have contacts attached to them. So we implemented this by having a foreign key in our contacts table that pointed back to its owning user in the users table. But now we need to add functionality that requires a user to have a default contact. So I have added a column for the default contact of a user that points to the contacts table as a foreign key. Note the tables below.

The two tables (I have chopped them down to the relevant columns):

```
users table:
      user_id varchar(20) PK
      default_contact bigint FK to contacts.id (nullable)

contacts table:
      id bigint PK
      user_id varchar(20) FK to users.user_id
```

Notice the circular Foreign Keys.

Now I want to add a constraint to the users table that says that the default_contact can only be a contact that belongs to that user (ie. the contact's user_id == the user_id of the user who has it as a default contact). I am now stuck because I am unsure how to add this constraint. This potentially could be solved by an assertion, but as I am using SqlServer assertions are not supported. This must be a common problem, because this is the second time in two days that we have come across a similar scenario in two completely different cases.

So is it even possible to add this constraint? If so, how would I go about doing so?

---

### EDIT -- Jan 15 2014 03:39 UTC

So I have found one way I can do this, which is to add the constraint in via checks in a stored procedure. This will work as long as we always access the users.default_contact field via stored procedure, but I was wondering if there are any other strict solutions.

Comment: I'd have an `is_default` column in the contacts table and then implement a constraint to ensure that only one is set per `user_id`. That's simple to achieve declaratively (via filtered index or indexed view) and avoids heaping on more work (e.g. the function that you've accepted does nothing to prevent a contact having its `user_id` column updated to correct which user a contact belongs to)

Comment: No because I actually simplified it, we actually have two different defaults pointing to the same table, but a contact could be both or one of the contacts depending on the type of contact, so that is not feasible. And we don't want to prevent a contact from moving between different user_ids

Comment: Also it would seem a lot more work to manage that is_default column on the contacts table than it would be on the users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SQL Server` you could use a combination of techniques to achieve this. A common one would be using a combination of [Check Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [User-Defined Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx). This way when you add the constraint to the users table, everytime you perform an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement the constraint will validate the value specified for the default contact.

Firstly you will need to create the function...

```
create function ValidateContact(@userid int, @contact int)
returns bit
as
begin
   declare @count int,
           @retVal bit;

   select @count = count(*) from dbo.contacts where user_id = @userid and id = @contact

   if @count = 0 and @contact is not null
    set @retVal =  0;
    else
    set @retVal =  1;

   return @retVal;
end
go
```

This function will receive two parameters (userid and contact) and then checks whether the contact exists for the user. If it doesn't, it returns 0 (false) otherwise it returns 1 (true). The you will need to create the `CHECk` constraint...

```
alter table dbo.users
add constraint chk_default_contact 
check (dbo.ValidateContact(user_id, default_contact) = 1)
go
```

Now, everytime you perform an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement the `CHECK` constraint will validate the input based on the logic specified in the `ValidateContact` function, if the validation fails, an error is thrown and the transaction is aborted.

Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you so much, this absolutely worked. I never thought to integrate a function into it.